# In-App-Purchase Parse Error 146

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, in-app-purchase

I have set up a button to remove ads using Parse. When I press it, I am getting an error that says parse error 146. I followed this video to convert to swift and the coding is all correct. I found that the error 146 means that your in app purchase is not connected to itunes connect but I made sure it is. I also deleted my app off my phone and redownloaded it. Does it matter that my bank and tax info is not set up on itunes connect? Or is it something else? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

yes it matters. You need to configure all the banking, contact, and tax before it will work. You then need to wait an hour or two for it to go through the system. Once the warning notification (to complete the bank, tax, contact info etc) above the in-app purchase disappears, you can start testing.

Comment: If this is indeed the case (haven't tested it yet) I'll be very thankful. Quick question on the tax info, I have a LLC (multiple members) and I'm wondering if I should click "exempt" or "subject to withholdings". From what I've read, I'm thinking the LLC is exempt (because 2. I have not been notified by the Internal Revenue Service (IRS) that I am subject to backup withholding as a result of a failure to report all interest or dividends.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this response is years later... but the only thing you need to ensure is that you have the in-app purchases included in your 'capabilities' for the app. Direct message me if you have questions.

Also, I wrote a comment to an answer above a year+ ago... you are NOT SUBJECT to backhanding unless specifically told so. So do NOT check this unless you KNOW you should. Hope this helps someone.